# When JVM is Heap gets released

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jvm

I need to monitor the JVM space when the application is running i used JMC to monitor but when i stop the tomcat JMC is not working.

My goal is i need to verify that when the application is down all the heap memory(or some-part) is getting released and how much it releases.

Is there any tool to monitor? If yes, Suggest me.

my understanding is when the tomcat or no java process is running Heap will be automatically gets released.Correct me if am wrong

Comment: "when the application is down" - do you mean when the process is terminated, or when there's not much to do for the application that keeps running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a tool like `top` or `vmstat` to (crudely) monitor how much physical and virtual memory is in use.

But basically Thomas is correct:

- A JVM is a Linux process.
- A JVM exiting is equivalent to its process exiting.
- When a Linux process exits, all resources that it owns (exclusively) are released: memory, native threads, file descriptors, sockets, pipes ... and even detached files.  The OS takes care of this.

In short, you don't need to worry about a JVM consuming resources after it has exited.

Answer (score 2):

The Java heap is part of the memory the Java process allocates. Once the Java VM terminates, all resources including the memory are released.

Comment: To clarify, that is not specific to Java processes. The Operating System will automatically release all system resources (incl. memory) when a process ends, regardless of the language used to write the process code.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the application is stopped, the process is terminated and the memory is released to the operating system

> Note that as soon as the process ends, there is no GC or anything else
>   related to the JVM, because all that stuff only works as long as the
>   JVM is running.

Answer (score 0):

As quoted by Stephen C, you should not worry about releasing of memory post application exit.

`free -m` command will display available memory on linux node. You can verify free memory usage with this command.

> free displays the total amount of free and used physical and swap memory in the system, as well as the buffers and caches used by the kernel. The information is gathered by parsing /proc/meminfo.